# How do I correct syntax highlight in VS Code for PHP 8.1 Enum Class?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-8.1

My Code:

```php
namespace App\Enum;

enum HomeStatus: string
{
    case RENT = 'rent';
    case MOVE_IN = 'move_in';
    case SOLD = 'sold';
    case COMING_SOON = 'coming_soon';
}
```

The code above is executing and working but the editor has the following error:

`Unexpected 'Name'. Expected ';'.intelephense(1001)`

I am using `Intelephense v1.8.0` which I believe is the latest.

In the Change Log it says:

`PHP 8.1 is now the default version.`

I'm thinking that either that's not the case or PHP 8.1 does not yet have support for enums.

Is there a way to resolve this or is this something that is not yet supported?

*EDIT* As requested here's a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be here, since there is no `Name` showing in your code. Can you show the code giving that error?

Comment: @aynber I agree the quotes are misleading, but that's seemingly the internal token name used by the language server. For example, if you type `class Foo {`, the error reads _Unexpected 'EndOfFile'_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open Visual Studio Code settings and ensure the `intelephense.environment.phpVersion` directive is set to `"8.1.0"` or greater. It can be set for the whole program or for specific projects.

[image: intelephense.environment.phpVersion]

```
{
    "intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I went into `settings.json` and I added `"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "8.1.0"`

Answer (score 4):

For me, Alvaro's solution was only half of the fix. I also had to update this setting to point to my PHP executable.

```php
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C://laragon//bin//php//php-8.1.3-Win32-vs16-x64//php.exe"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when using WSL

Comment: This setting doesn't belong to PHP Intelephense, it's from builtin PHP Language Features which, according to [Quick Start](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client), needs to be disabled.